# Auto-Increment Integer Field in a Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

Does anyone know of a good way of auto-incrementing an integer field within a SDE feature class when the feature is created?  I don't want to have a script run afterwards to populate the field and I'd like this to be run when a feature is created (insert).

Is there a trigger that could be run or can the Identity property be used?

Just wondering if anyone has a good solution for this?

ArcGIS Version = 10.2.1

ArcSDE = 10.1 sp1

RDBMS = SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the duplicate question...?

Comment: The link to the duplicate question appears at the top of this one.